# java_web_start_IP_Hostname_specification

Tags: jnlp, java-web-start

I have checked my jnlp file using JaNeLa and corrected the errors.

Is there any way out so that I can specify the remote server's **IP** and **Hostname** in the JNLP file as a property.

Somehow Like :

```
<property name="remoteIP" value="172.58.198.117"/>
<property name="hostname" value="rhel5"/>
```

My application is a CORBA application which I am deploying from tomcat server in my machine. But the CORBA server is a remote RHEL5 (Enterprise Linux 5) machine.

In this web start scenario as I scrutinized the remote CORBA server machine cannot be detected, that's why all these errors and problems are occurring.

In my machine I have declared the IP and hostname entry in **"C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"** file. When I used to run the CORBA apps from jar simply using batch file the server machine can be detected easily by reading the host file and application works fine. But in Web Start I need to take special action and provide **IP** and **Hostname** of remote machine somehow.

Answer (score 0):

In the jnlp file you can send arguments to your application's main-method using

```
<application-desc main-class="Main">
    <argument>1.2.3.4</argument>
    <argument>hostname</argument>
</application-desc>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#application_desc

Then you would need to modify your application to take care of these arguments.

Another alternative, which requires all jar-files to be signed, is to

run the application in unrestricted mode [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#security), it should be able to read any file you want on the filesystem

```
<security>
   <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Aksel Willgert... I have successfully managed to launch the application...

Comment: If an answer solved your problem you may accept/upvote the answer to show others this is infact a solution the question you have asked